# error getting the api key using restsharp

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

I was not able to retrieve my api key and user id. I used the `Console.WriteLine` to check my values, and they were just empty. 
Shouldn't I be able to retrieve those values?

```
var client = new RestClient("http://myproject/");
                var request = new RestRequest("api/ApiKey?email=" + email + "&password=" + password, Method.GET);

                var queryResult = client.Execute(request);

                if (queryResult.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    var deserial = new JsonDeserializer();
                    var x = deserial.Deserialize<ApiKey>(queryResult);

                    Application.Current.Properties["ApiKey"] = x.UserApiKey;
                    Application.Current.Properties ["UserId"] = x.UserId;

                    Console.WriteLine ("here");
                    Console.WriteLine ("key:"+x.UserApiKey);
                    //do this
                }
                else
                {
                    // do this

                }
```

Comment: did you check `queryResult.Content` in debug? what does it hold?

Comment: @Omribitan : Yes and it holds: {"ApiKey":"rY88liT/BE98t2e3SLXnCQ==","UserId":1}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `queryResult.Content` holds the following json structure:

```
 {
     "ApiKey":"rY88liT/BE98t2e3SLXnCQ==",
     "UserId":1
 }
```

The object you are deserializing to should look like this:

```
public class ApiKeyOjbect
{
     public string ApiKey { get; set; }
     public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

And an esier way to do it would be to serialize the result directly

```
var queryResult = client.Execute<ApiKeyOjbect>(request);
```

Comment: name of the class and data field ApiKey is same?

Comment: @AabiRegmi no, my mistake. fixed it